# Gnome terminal does not take lowercase 'a' input from keyboard

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

my Ubuntu terminal doesn't take lowercase letter 'a' only. Also it parses 'a' every time I copy some text in terminal containing 'a'. For 'a',  now I have to use Insert+a every time.
The lower-case 'a' input works fine everywhere else in Ubuntu, except the terminal only.

I  have also checked the keyboard layout,but it same as it was set before.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Have you gone through all your bash config files yet?

Comment: Hello fabby, Thank you..:) Yes i did..Finally i had find an alternate soution. I had added the line "bind '"a":self-insert'" in the bashrc file and forcefully adding it.

Comment: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

OP's own answer:

Finally I found an alternate soution: I had added the line "

```
bind '"a":self-insert'
```

in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file and that solved the problem.